# In Flask framework @app.route('/') , how route('/') function is used as a decorator from app object?

Tags: python, flask

In the Flask framework, `app` is an object and `route('/')` is a function which is used as a decorator. Can anybody tell me what the mechanism behind this decorator? How is the `route('/')` method is called?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: `app` has a callable attribute `route` which returns a decorator. This decorator is applied to the function `hello_world` with the `@`-syntax, modifying the function. Your question is a bit vague, are you trying to understand (parameterized) decorators or the specific implementation of `route`?

Comment: Thank you  sir for reply and precious time, I am little bit confused, I saw app as app.py in modules but here app word is used as variable or object of Flask  ,here approach to decorators are different from normal decorator that I learned in tutorials. As you said it is a parameterized decorator . I have read the documentation but still I want clarity about what @app is a variable or a file. I tried to explain everything that I wanted to ask.

Comment: Anuj, in your comment you are asking if `app` is a variable or a file. That is a very (!) different question than what I can make from the actual question text. Also, it seems like you are asking multiple questions. Please focus on ONE question and try to formulate that one as clearly as possible. That might get it reopened (although I'm 99% sure it will be a duplicate question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `app` has no direct relation to the file app.py. You could name both of them differently.

`app.route('/')` is a function call that returns a decorator, which then is applied to `hello_world`.

You could write

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

as

```
root_decorator = app.route('/')

@root_decorator
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

or as

```
root_decorator = app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

hello_world = root_decorator(hello_world)
```

Here's a mock of what happens:

```
class Flask:
    def route(self, path):
        def decorator(function):
            def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
                print(f'path is {path!r}. doing some Flask magic now.')
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            return new_function
        return decorator

app = Flask()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Demo:

```
>>> result = hello_world()
path is '/'. doing some Flask magic now.
>>> result
'Hello, World!'
```